# How should one pronounce CiviCRM?

Tags: best-practice

How do you pronounce civicrm when speaking to others? Is it "civi" or "civik-c-r-m?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CiviCRM: *Sih-Vee See Ar Em*

Civi (for short): *Sih-Vee*

Comment: ... and of course Civi being civi- as in civic and civil, not kiwi.

Comment: I've heard "SIV-ee" much more commonly but also "SIV-ih" on some occasions. I'd love to know which one is recommended by the core team.

Comment: @SeanMadsen At that level, it is likely to depend on your accent, just as some pronounce *Wikipedia* with three syllables and others four or five. I might consult conference videos to see how lobo pronounces it, but then, rather few English speakers pronounce *Linux* the way Linus Torvalds does, so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: @choster Ehm, _Wikipedia_ in three syllables?

Comment: @MrLister For example, /wɪkˈpiːdʒə/ in some accents.

Comment: @choster Oh, OK. Wik peed yuh. Thanks. I never heard it like that.

Answer (score 3):

Sih-Vee-See-Are-Em. In a perfect Toronto accent. ;) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207687/how-are-you-supposed-to-pronounce-fragile/207688#207688

More seriously, as the CRM is always pronounced See-Are-Em, there is no 'C' left at the end of CiviCRM to justify a hard k sound at the end. So for me, there is no way to make CiviCRM sound like Civic-CRM.

Though come to think of it, Civic Relationship Management does have a nice twist to it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

CIV-ee-see-are-EM

(capitals for emphasis)

Answer (score 2):

Sih Vih See Are Em, but Sivee for short

Nobody looks at you funny for saying Sivee See Are Em, but like lynxlynxlyxn says in the comment on Shawn's answer, it comes from "civic": CiviCRM is a portmanteau of civic and CRM.

Comment: < flame > Ah, NO WAY are we going to let Andrew's regional Southern US accent set the standard here! </flame> The proper pronunciation is halfway between American and British English, namely, Sih-Vee-See-Are-Em.

Comment: @JoeMurray - Just couldn't help yourself, eh? Nonetheless, I think we've adequately covered the linguistic characteristics of the name.

Comment: There's something nicely Canajun about that eh, eh? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Start with **Civi** (however you pronouce that) and then speak the letters **C R M** (however you pronounce those) and you can't go wrong.

And if CiviCRM is too many syllables (or you want to get affectionate)  shorten it to **Civi**.

I don't want to get all dogmatic about it but IMO some people mistakenly say "**Civic C R M**" (with an extra C) or "**Civic R M**" (moving the C from the start of CRM to the end of Civi).

Having said all that, we are an easy going and also a very diverse bunch of people from around the world, hence we don't worry too much about pronunciation and are happy for our name to get 'localized'.

Some silly pronunciations that I sometimes use for fun include "**CiviCream**" and "**CiviCrumb**" :)

Answer (score 0):

For local use I also use our locale's way to pronounce abbreviations and initialisms, in this case transliterated to:

TSEEVEE TSuh Ruh Muh (`uh` representing the [schwa](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/Schwa-term.htm), Simpsons-style)